# Needs tips on AJAX

Tags: ajax

Im going to start AJAX can someone help, guide me to how should i do it ,where should i learn it from.
(I have membership in Lynda they have a course on AJAX [only 2 hours long] i don't think that would be enough. right?).

Comment: yes but i dont know the ajax part

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I recommend this method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax_controller.php', //url to u controller in PHP
    data: { //Data transmitted to the controller
        id: id,
        action: 'delete'
    }
}).done(function(result){
    console.log(result);//show controller result in console
});
```